# 301 redirect from double slash to one slash in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect some urls with 301 status code

**Example:**

from www.domain.com//brands/ to www.domain.com/brands/

from www.domain.com//brands/brand1 to www.domain.com/brands/brand1

I've tried this

```
Redirect 301 //brands/ /brands/
```

It mostly works. But on this url doesn’t 
 `www.domain.com/brands/brand1` gets redirected to `www.domain.com/brandsbrand1`

Answer (score 2):

try this rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule / http://www.example.com/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

also you can try with RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)//+(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2
```

Comment: No, it do not work, My .htaccess file following.

RewriteEngine on

#Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

Comment: No, not work redirect. Thank you for your help.  But problem not solved

Answer (score 2):

I solved with php.

I used following code:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "//") !== false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "///") !== false){
  $url = str_replace("///", "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $url = str_replace("//", "/", $url);
  $protocol = "http";
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
   $protocol = "https";
  }
  $url_final = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url;
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: $url_final");
}
```